# Is it possible to scale a set of adjacent faces to a middle point on a single axis?

Tags: modeling, scale

I'm selecting a rounded edge of adjacent faces, and I want to scale them all to the same flat value in Y-axis. I'm new to Blender, but I was able to do this in Maya.

Comment: Hello, could you add an illustration ?

Comment: Perhaps select the faces and scale on the y axis by pressing  S  and press  0 and then press enter . I hope that was what you were looking for . It's hard to say without a picture...